# Installing linux without USB flash drive using a partition. Boot menu doesn't recognize the partition

Tags: linux-mint, dual-boot, boot-loader

I am a newbie and I am planning to get Linux along with windows on my system using a dual boot setup. The issue is I have taken a round about way because i don't have a USB. So here is what I have done so far.

I created a new partition G: on the hard disk of the format FAT32, which can serve as the flash usb. Then i used universal usb installer to put the linux ISO image into the G: drive. [the universal usb installer settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKsQ9.png)

However, when I restart I can't see the G: drive as another option on the boot menu, [my laptop's one time boot menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4ehd.jpg). Moreover, I have dell inspiron 15 5510 and its one time boot menu looks completely different from the ones I have seen in tutorial videos.

So I am planning to add another boot menu entry using bcdedit commands it's just........I am scared. (Two days ago I didn't even knew what UEFI was and yet here I am interfering with my machines boot menu)

More about what else I tried. I did try Unetbootin, because it can install linux without usb however, it doesn't seem to work well on UEFI boot mode. It kept showing this screen- [the error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjFEh.jpg) (even after disabling secure boot) every time I entered Unetbootin from boot menu. Also my laptop doesn't support legacy mode, that's where i gave up on Unetbootin approach.

Comment: You need to have at least two USB flash drives for potential repairs, just in case. I also have multiple flash drives with full installs and/or repair type ISO that I can boot with. If your install is not perfect, the only way to fix it would be with a flash drive. To boot an extracted ISO in a FAT32 partition, you have to change boot,esp flags to that partition. Then that will be the only bootable partition. If install does not work then the only way you can move boot flag back is with repair flash drive. I have done what you are doing but only on an external SSD that has full install, also.

Comment: 1/ you state you're a newbie 2/ you won't follow intended installation method 3/ you risk losing your (only?) system . Just don't do it. Wait till you can afford an USB key.

Comment: As I understand your installation process so far, you have written a partitioned drive onto a partition. It cannot work. USB images are partitioned drives. Your computer's one-time boot menu lists bootable *drives* (hdd, usb, cdrom), not partitions. It's the *booloader* (e.g. grub, lilo, syslinux) installed on a bootable drive that sees bootable partitions. I also agree with the above comment that this might be risky business.

Comment: Nonetheless, +1 for trying. With Linux, you'll be able to use partitions as virtual drives.